# JavaScript / JQuery variable need to change.. on click. Delete old number add new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to get the random number generated to change to another random number once clicked on a button.  I also cannot figure out how to unselect the form selected I'm trying how to below with jQuery.

```
var randomNum1 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
var randomNum2 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
var randomNum3 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
var randomNum4 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
$( "#race-again" ).click(function()
    {   
    $( ".one" ).css( { marginLeft: "0" });
    $( ".two" ).css({ marginLeft: "0" });
    $( ".three" ).css( { marginLeft: "0" });
    $( ".four" ).css( { marginLeft: "0" });
    $( "#slide2" ).animate( { marginTop: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
    $( "#slide3" ).animate( { marginTop: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
    $( "#slide4" ).animate( { marginTop: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
    $( "#slide5" ).animate( { marginTop: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
    $( "#betting-money" ).val("0");
    $( "#results" ).hide("");
    $( "#winner" ).hide("");
    $( "#next-end" ).hide("");
//trying to unselect the form input selection
 $("#race input option:selected").attr("selected", "");    
//new random number generated... which doesn't work
    var randomNum1 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
    var randomNum2 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
    var randomNum3 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
    var randomNum4 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are declaring different variables in a different scope. Try removing `var` the second time you set the variables:

```
randomNum1 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
randomNum2 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
randomNum3 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
randomNum4 = Math.ceil(Math.random(20)*10000);
```

And it would help to see the HTML code for the form that you're trying to unselect.

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you are declaring new local variables with the same names as the global variables. Instead of this:

```
var randomNum1 = ...
```

use:

```
randomNum1 = ...
```

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to unseelect. If it is an input element, it doesn't have any option children. If it is a select element, which can have option children, you can't unselect an option, you select a different option.

To remove focus from an input element you use the `blur` method:

```
$("#race input").blur();
```

To unselect a select option, you select another option:

```
$("#race select").val("0");
```

---

By the way, your random number calculation is flawed. The `Math.random` method doesn't take a parameter, and it returns a value that is equal or larger than zero, and less than one. If you use `Math.ceil` to get the numbers in the range 0..10000, the value 0 will occur much more seldom than the other numbers.

To get a correctly distributed number in the range 0..10000, use `Math.floor` and multiply with 10001:

```
randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10001);
```

If you intended to get a result in the range 1..10000, you should add one:

```
randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the selected-issue:

Use

```
$("#race option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

1. option isn't a child of an input(the selector is wrong)
2. when you use `attr()` you set the html-attribute, but this attribute does only have one valid value: `"selected"` . `prop()` sets the `"selected"`-property instead, which may have the values `false or true`